# ffmpeg generate thumbnail with aspect ratio, but X seconds into video

Tags: php, ffmpeg

So this command works for generating a thumbnail 5 seconds into the video, with a size of 300x300:

```
$cmd = '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i '.$this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$fname.' -ss 00:00:05 -f image2 -vframes 1 -s 300x300 '.$this->getUploadRootDir().'/thumb_'.$output;
```

However, I want to keep the aspect ratio so I changed my code to this:

```
$cmd = "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i ".$this->getUploadRootDir()."/".$fname." -ss 00:00:5 -f image2 scale='min(300\, iw):-1' ".$this->getUploadRootDir()."/thumb_".$output;
```

The above code correctly sizes the image, however it's of the first frame in the video.. I need the thumbnail to be 5 seconds in. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Didn't you forget the `-filter:v` before `scale`?

Comment: @slhck yep, you should post that as the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do that with a command line similar to:

```
ffmpeg -i inputVideo -vf scale='min(300,iw)':-1 -ss 00:00:05 -f image2 -vframes 1 thumbnail.jpg
```

So in your script, add `-vf` (video filter) before scale and reorder input and output parameters like below:

```
$cmd = "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i ".$this->getUploadRootDir()."/".$fname." -vf scale='min(300\, iw):-1' -ss 00:00:5 -f image2 -vframes 1 ".$this->getUploadRootDir()."/thumb_".$output;
```

Answer (score -1):

@alexbuisson has the correct answer, but just to confirm as I'm playing with ffmpeg today:

This works for me:

```
ffmpeg -i "my_video.mp4" -ss 00:00:05 -f image2 -vf scale="min(300\, iw):-1" -vframes 1 "capture.jpg"
```

I get one Jpeg 300 px wide with the correct image ratio.

So adapted to your code this becomes:

```
$cmd = "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i ".$this->getUploadRootDir()."/".$fname." -ss 00:00:05 -f image2 -vf scale='min(300\, iw):-1' ".$this->getUploadRootDir()."/thumb_".$output;
```